# Calling javascript function from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe on the page and I am trying to call a function on the parent page form the iframe. I noticed that when i use:

```
window.top
```

that works fine in Chrome. However, when i use:

```
window.parent
```

that works for IE.

How can i write a method that checks both and uses the correct method? Also i am using jquery and was trying to find a way use that to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Be aware of the same origin policy.  Parent will only work if both the frame and the page with the frame are on the same domain.  If not, consider using something like easyXDM.  http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Answer (score 0):

So i doing something wrong for some reason but parent.function() works fine in all browser. Sorry for confusion